# Nokogiri+Paperclip = XML parse with img from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, paperclip, nokogiri

I need to parse some params to my DB and image from URL.

I use paperclip for image.

In Rails console I can add image to new post by this code:

```
    image = Image.new
    image.image_from_url "http://yug-avto.ru/files/image/tradein/hyundai/877_VOLKSWAGEN_FAETON_2011_2_1366379491.jpg"
    image.watermark = true
    image.save!
```

in my Image model I have

```
require "open-uri"
.......
def image_from_url(img_url)
  self.image = open(img_url)
end
```

And all work done. But when I use Nokogiri, this code don't work.

```
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - 
http://yug-avto.ru/files/image/tradein/peugeot/1027_Peugeot_308_2011_2_1370850441.jpg
```

My rake task for Nokogiri parse:

```
doc.xpath("//item").each do |ad|
 img = ad.at("image").text

 img1 = Image.new
 img1.image = open("#{img}") 
 img1.watermark = true
 img1.save!
end
```

In rake task for Nokogiri, I have require 'nokogiri' and require 'open-uri'.

How to be?:))))

Comment: are you using ImageMagick aswell? Or solely paperclip?

Comment: add 'require "open-uri"' -- that will allow you to open HTTP paths as well as local files.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott he is already doing so...

Comment: @TheChamp you're right! I missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a code snippet from my parser... I guess where you went wrong is using `open(url)` instead of `parse(url)`.

```
picture = Picture.new(
    realty_id: realty.id,
    position: position,
    hashcode: realty.hashcode
)
# picture.image = URI.parse(url), edit: added open() as this worked for Savroff
picture.image = open(URI.parse(url))
picture.save!
```

Additionally it would be a good idea to check if the image really exists

```
picture_array.each do |url|

    # checks if the Link works
    res = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))

    # if so, it will add the Picture Link to the verified Array
    if res.code.to_i >= 200 && res.code.to_i < 400 #good codes will be betweem 200 - 399
        verified_array << url
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks TheChamp, you led me to the right thoughts. 
First need to parse URL and after that open.

```
image = Image.new
ad_image_url = URI.parse("#{img}")
image.image = open(ad_image_url)
image.watermark = true
image.save!
```